# Pagination using AngularFire2

Tags: firebase, pagination, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angularfire2

I am building an Ionic2 project, that uses Firebase and I am using AngularFire2.

From AngularFire2 documentation, I was able to get things like:

```
const queryObservable = af.database.list('/items', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'size',
    equalTo: subject 
  }
});
```

This works well. I have around 300-400 records, but I can't pull it all in one API call. So I am trying to implement pagination.  I tried many things. What I want to implement is [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt):

```
StartAt(), endAt()
```

I tried to pass it through the query object, but it did not work. 
Does AngularFire2 have an implementation for this? 
If not, how can I get the Firebase ref so that I can write my own implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularFire2 does support `startAt` and `endAt` according to their [source code](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/firebase_list_factory.ts). Here's how you would limit your query based on a list with a child key of `size`:

```
let queryObservable = this.af.database.list('/items', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'size',
    startAt: 50,
    endAt: 100
  }
});
```

This should pull all the items that have a child key of `size` defined between 50 to 100.

**NOTE** I have noticed that if I were to pass in a reference object into AngularFire2 instead of a reference path, the query will **NOT** work! So the code below will still return the list of items but it will not be sorted properly.

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('/items');
this.af.database(ref, { query: { orderByChild: 'size' } });
```

Comment: how do you do pagination if you cant do a simple count of the db rows? And the workarround for that brings all the data at once, so why would you query it again with an start/end limit? i am missing anything?

Comment: One way around it is to have a child key of `order` where it's an incremental counter 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. Then you can use `orderByChild: 'order'`, `startAt: 10` and `endAt: 19` to fetch the 2nd page of entries 10-19.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at this problem in a [blog post](https://thielcole.github.io/ionic2/2016/11/15/pagination-angularfire2.html) recently, but you bring up an interesting edge case where your total query will be larger than you want to pull. I would solve this with the same methodology as before, but implementing a start at and end at instead of a limitToLast. Also, you use BehaviorSubjects imported from rxjs because they will allow you to get the current value and increment by a certain amount. Example

```
let firstKey = new BehaviorSubject(''); // import 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'
let nextKey = new BehaviorSubject('');
let pageSize = new BehaviorSubject(10);

let queryObservable = this.af.database.list('/items', {
 query: {
   orderByKey: true,
   startAt: firstKey,
   limitToFirst: pageSize
 }
});
```

Now you have a constantly moving window starting with the first key and using the keys as the value you are sorting on. To be able to change the key, you need to store the key you want in a particular place, for example.

```
queryObservable.subscribe((data) => {
    // angularfire2 adds a $key property to each result in an array
    // Does not handle the edge case at the end of the list
  if (data.length === pageSize.getValue()) {
    nextKey.next(data.$key);
  }
});
```

To increase and decrease the window, just change the firstKey value to the value of nextKey.

```
firstKey.next(nextKey.getValue());
```

You can do all sorts of neat things, like add multiple pages, or go back a page with small tweaks to this methodology. This is as opposed to adding fields that you have to maintain in your database, which can be cumbersome in some cases.

Comment: when I try retrieve the data my $key is always undefined. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I've also need to do simple paging (Next and Previous) with Angular 2 and Firebase.

My solution is to querying an extra item from the list `itemPerPage + 1` and keeping that as reference. Then using the `startAt` and `endAt` options I'm able to page next and previous on my data with the reference item.

I've created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/DawidvanGraan/839e0c6ae0262fe3a74d153698a45f6d) to show my solution, hope it can help.